# How to un-stem 'Jesu' to get 'Jesus' in wordcloud?

Tags: word-cloud, stemming

Trying to get a .png image using wordcloud from a book on Bible. The word 'Jesus' is stemmed to 'Jesu'. Is there a way to give an exception to this one word alone? Strangely, 'Moses' is not stemmed.

```
{file_content = open("Wheres_Heaven.txt").read()}

{wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=None, background_color = 'white', width=1200, height=1000, max_words = 500, ).generate(file_content)}

{plt.figure( figsize=(20,10) )
{plt.imshow(wordcloud)}
{plt.axis('off')}
{plt.savefig('Heaven.png')}
{plt.show()}
```

[Heaven.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjtNf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have version [1.8.1](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/commit/905a960979736f6dc708e8127c7ef5c320305bec) then you can put "Jesu" in stopwords.

The logic is when it sees both "Jesu" and "Jesus" in the text, the code assumes it is a plural. Apparently the text has no "Mose", which is why that was not treated as plural.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I appended the word 'Jesu' to my wordcloud stopwords and ran the code. The result was exactly as I wanted.